# Entropy change of an elastic cylinder

Tags: thermodynamics

We had in our thermodynamics class an example regarding the entropy change of a rubber cylinder.It has an initial length $L_0$ and after we stretch it it has a final length $L_f$.A thermodynamic state equation regarding the force acting on the cylinder was given f(T,L), which I don't think it's very important right now to write down, as it is not this the problem I am having. So anyway we proceed and write the following down:

$dF= -SdT + fdl$

The sign is positive as a stretching of the rubber cylinder, increases it's internal energy (in difference from when we have the expansion of a gas).

Then it is said that since the free energy is a state variable then:

$\frac {\partial S(T,L)}{\partial L} + \frac {\partial f(T,L)}{\partial T}=0$.

How is the fact that the free energy F is a state variable, the reason for us receiving the above equation ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By state variable, people mean that the free energy is completely specified by the 2 (thermodynamic) coordinates T, and L (and not by "how" you reached that state).

A small change in F can be then decomposed by partials with respect to each coordinate:
$$ dF = \underbrace{\partial_{T} F}_{\equiv -S} dT + \underbrace{\partial_{L} F}_{\equiv f} dL $$

This allows us to identify what S and f are: they are just the partials of F with respect to the thermodynamic variables.
$$ \rightarrow S = -\partial_T F(L, T) $$
$$ \rightarrow f = \partial_L F(L, T) $$

Because partial derivatives commute, we have:
$$ \partial_L \partial_T F = \partial_T \partial_L F$$
$$ -\partial_L S = \partial_T f$$
which is what you want.

Comment: Yes this helped me, to understand the step I couldn't, but in the book we have this eq. $\frac {\partial S(T,L)}{\partial L} + \frac {\partial f(T,L)}{\partial T}=0$ where is this derived from? Because after we obtain this, we reach your last step/ equality. This is what confuses me

Comment: The equality from the book is derived from my equation.  Just move the terms to one side and you have that relation.  The series of steps I highlighted is the reasoning you use to go from F is state variable to -> $\partial_l S + \partial_T f = 0$

Comment: Yes but in the book we start with this, and end up with your last equation. That's why I was so confused all the time

Comment: I don't understand: I started from your beginning equation and ended at your last equation.  Isn't that what your book did?

Comment: My book only gave me the 2nd equality, which comes from your last equality not the reverse. Anyway, I was able to understand it, so that's what matters, thx!

Answer (score 0):

If F is a state variable, then $$S=-\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial T}\right)_l$$and$$f=\left(\frac{\partial F}{\partial l}\right)_T$$